# How can I play asciinema screen-recording inside org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, animate

I was wondering, is it possible to play [asciinema.org](https://asciinema.org) screen recordings inside org-mode using embed the player?

Here is an example link of a screen recording: https://asciinema.org/a/418574. Note that its original format is `.cast`.

---

Three approaches provided by `asciinema.org`:

1. HTML:

```
<a href="https://asciinema.org/a/418574" target="_blank"><img src="https://asciinema.org/a/418574.svg" /></a>
```

2. Markdown:

```
[![asciicast](https://asciinema.org/a/418574.svg)](https://asciinema.org/a/418574)
```

3. Embed the player:

```
<script id="asciicast-418574" src="https://asciinema.org/a/418574.js" async></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. Why did you expect that you can?

You can however display inline images; see [chapter 12.7 Images](https://orgmode.org/manual/Images.html) of the Org Mode manual.

Comment: I was hoping to display it as a gif

Comment: @alper you can turn asciinema recording into a gif with https://github.com/asciinema/agg

Comment: @sickill but can we display gif in org-mode? like displaying inline images?

Comment: @alper I don't know if org-mode supports gif files, sorry.